# Can't query pymongo unicode database names

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB server populated with several databases. These databases all hold pieces of data used in aggregation of some calculations I do on some dataset. These databases are all created in Python 3. Most of the data is retrieved by the client-side of my tool, which is in python3 as well and works just fine, no problems querying. However, I run into problems when I try to access a specific database from a separate server than *only* has python2.7 installed (I have no control over that). When I print the database names to see what they look like, I get something like this:

```
>>> print(client.database_names())
[u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E']
```

Note: They only look this way on the server with python2.7 installed.

Let's say I'm looking for the contents of database 'B', which I know is populated since I check from my server using python3. It doesn't seem to want to pull the right database by name, no matter what I try. This is what I've tried:

```
>>>db = client[unicode('B')]
>>>print (db.collection_names())
[]

>>>db = client[u'B']
>>>print (db.collection_names())
[]

>>>db = client['B']
>>>print (db.collection_names())
[]
```

attempt 2

```
# Python 2.7 pymongo test script
import pymongo
ip_address = "some ip address"

client = pymongo.MongoClient(ip_address)
db_names = client.database_names()

for i in range(len(db_names)):
    if (unicode('B') == db_names[i]):
        print ('foo')
        db = client[db_names[i]]
        break

print (db.collection_names())
##
## OUTPUT

## foo
## []
```

I'm not else how to overcome this problem. Is it something with writing to the database? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**:

I did a bit more digging and found that the problem is definitely a result of using two different versions of Python. I haven't figured out a solution yet.

Comment: Did you try client['B'.encode('utf-8')] ?

Comment: Yeah, no luck there either

Comment: Are your DB names really A, B, etc. or did you change? Is the original name 100% ASCII? Because I made a test of a python2 client to a DB created in Python3, it works fine with a simple DB name like `test`

Comment: The names are made up of 100% ascii characters, but they aren't single character strings like 'A', 'B', and 'C'. I did that to show simply what I meant. How did you create the python3 database? That might be where my problem is.

Comment: The database is automatically created whenever a Python3 client tries to write into a collection. `client['DBNAME']` will always return a database instance, no matter if it exists or not. If it does not exist it is created on collections operations. Did you try getting the DB name from an API call rather than writing it yourself? Try `c[c.database_names()[0]].collection_names()`

Comment: Right, I went ahead and tried to copy what you did. No, I'm doing it all myself. Does db.collection_names() work on the python2 side for yours? It seems even when I create a database in python2 and I create a collection in that db without trashing the variable, I still get '[]' when I print the collection names from the db. I'll have to experiment a bit more, thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: Yes `collection_names()` works on Python 2 client and `c[c.database_names()[0]].collection_names()`  does work on my side. Note that it also gives me unicode encoded strings as results.

Comment: I think I might have an old version, this does not work. I still get an empty list. Thanks! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your user has all needed privileges, its a classic privilege problem.

Comment: I haven't needed to set any user privileges, what do you mean by this? Would it potentially be a server-privilege or a mongod-privilege problem?

Comment: connect to the mongo directly and try to see the collections unser each db

using the mongo cli
do:
`use <db name>`
`show collections`

Do you see it ok?

Comment: Can't use the mongo client. I only have the binaries for pymongo installed on the server in question. However, I can run it with python3 on the test server and it shows up alright, so I don't think that's the problem. Thanks, though!